# Why is JavaScript in the query string executing?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, webforms, xss

I have an XSS situation where if a user saves a value like `"<img onerror=alert(document.cookie)>"` it will alert the cookie cookie when the page loads. The value is in the URL like `http://mything.com?value=onerror%253Dalert%2528document.cookie%2529%253E%26`.

Now the weird part is that it's executing even before any of the DOM has been parsed. I know because I changed the value to have `"onerror=debugger;"` and when I then loaded the page it would break before the `<html>` tag (i.e. before any tags). So it's not being called from any JavaScript file. I'm guessing this is a server-side issue? Any ideas?

Comment: What does the server code do with the `value` parameter?

Comment: I was about to ask same as barmar. Of course none of it is being done alone, there is something somewhere in your code that it is executing or doing something with it. Search for a place getting value parameter.